# Use android.support.design.widget in Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, tabs, xamarin.android

I want to try this version of TabLayout in my Xamarin app:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout

But I can't figure out how to get a reference to it -- i.e. what package to add, and what namespace to use in Xamarin.

I did find a doc about a "tabLayout" here, but it doesn't seem like they are referring to the same one because they say it has been deprecated, which does not appear to apply to the one I want:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Nuget Package

- `Xamarin.Android.Support.Design`

#### Layout usage:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    ~~~
/>
```

#### Using example:

```
using Android.Support.Design.Widget;
```